# Standard representative for a coset space

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, homogeneous-spaces

**Motivation:**
finding convenient real coordinates for the full complex flag manifold $ \mathrm{Flag} \left( 1, \ldots, n \right) $.

**Details:**
Consider the Lie group $ \mathrm{SU} \left( n \right) $ and its maximal torus $ \mathrm{T} := 
\left( \mathrm{U} \left( 1 \right) \times \ldots \times \mathrm{U} \left( 1 \right) \right) \cap \mathrm{SU} \left( n \right) $ - i.e. the subgroup of diagonal matrices. We know that the complete flag manifold may be described as a coset space:
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{Flag} \left( 1, \ldots, n \right) = \mathrm{SU} \left( n \right) / \mathrm{T}  .
\end{equation}
Now, using the physicists' convention where the exponential map is defined by $ A \mapsto e^{iA} $, the Lie algebra $ \mathfrak{su} \left( n \right) $ consists of traceless Hermitian matrices, and the torus is generated by the subalgebra $ \mathfrak{h} $ (a Cartan subalgebra of the complexified algebra), which consists of diagonal traceless Hermitian matrices. For example, for $ n = 2 $ we have that $ \mathfrak{su} \left( 2 \right) = \mathrm{Span}_{\mathbb{R}} \left\{ \sigma_x, \sigma_y , \sigma_z \right\} $ (the Pauli matrices) and $ \mathfrak{h} = \mathrm{Span}_{\mathbb{R}} \left\{ \sigma_z \right\} $.

Now, I read on lecture notes for some physics course that one can parametrize the coset space using what they call a *standard representative*. The groups involved were different, and no proof was given, but basically what it implies here is that one can parametrize the coset space using representatives of the form:
\begin{equation}
U \left(x, y \right) := e^{i \left( x \sigma_x + y\sigma_y \right)}
\end{equation}
That is, *any* $ V \in \mathrm{SU} \left( 2 \right) $ may be written in the form:
$$ V = e^{i \left( x \sigma_x + y\sigma_y \right)} e^{i z \sigma_z} \tag{1}\label{1} $$
for some $ x,y,z \in \mathbb{R} $. Thus, we obtain very convenient intrinsic real coordinates for $ \mathrm{Flag} \left( 1, 2 \right) $. Now, generally the RHS of \eqref{1} should be computed using the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula. However, for the case of $ \mathrm{SU} \left( 2 \right) $ the exponentials may be computed explicitly, so I was able to convince myself that this indeed works. My question is regarding $ n > 2 $.

**Question:** Let us label the generators of $ \mathfrak{su} \left( n \right) $ as follows: $ \left\{ H_1, \ldots, H_{n-1}, A_1, \ldots A_{n \left(n-1\right)} \right\} $, such that $ \left\{ H_1, \ldots, H_{n-1} \right\} $ are diagonal. Is it true that any matrix $ V \in \mathrm{SU} \left( n \right) $ may be written as a product of the following form?
$$ V = \exp \left(i \sum_j x_j A_j \right) \exp \left(i \sum_k y_k H_k\right) , \quad x_j, y_k \in \mathbb{R} . $$

Comment: I can prove this in the case where the $A_i$ have 0s in the non-diagonal slots (i.e., when the $A_i$ are orthgonal to the $H_i$ with respect to a bi-invariant metric).  Would you be interested in that special case?

Comment: The statement is true, cf [CCWZ](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.177.2247). You want a formal proof?

Comment: @JasonDeVito Yes, that special case is good enough for me, since it is always possible to choose such a basis for $ \mathfrak{su} (n) $.

Comment: @CosmasZachos A formal proof would be ideal, but any "convincing" argument (i.e. one I should be able to extend into a formal proof) will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually much more general.

Let $G$ denote any compact Lie group and $H\subseteq G$ a closed connected subgroup.  Let's pick a bi-invariant Riemannian metric on $G$.  Then, we obtain an orthogonal splitting $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{h}\oplus \mathfrak{p}$, where $\mathfrak{p}$ is merely a vector subspaces (i.e., it's not necessarily a sub-Lie algebra.)

The theorem is:

> Any $g\in G$ is of the form $\exp(Y)\exp(X)$ for some $X\in \mathfrak{h}$ and $Y\in \mathfrak{p}$.

Here's a sketch of a proof.  Given $g\in G$, let $\pi(g)$ denote the image of $g$ in the homogeneous space $G/H$.  Let $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow G/H$ be a minimal geodesic from $eH$ to $\pi(g)$ (where the metric on $G/H$ is induced from the chosen one on $G$ and where $e\in G$ is the identity element).  Then $\gamma$ has a unique horizontal lift to a geodesic $\overline{\gamma}$ in $G$ which begins at $e\in G$.

Being horizontal means that $\overline{\gamma}'(0)\in \mathfrak{p}$.  Since with respect to a bi-invariant metric, geodesics are the same as one parameter subgroups, it follows that $\overline{\gamma}(t) = \exp(tY)$ for some $Y\in \mathfrak{p}$.

Now, since $\pi\circ \overline{\gamma} = \gamma$, we see that $\pi(g) = \pi(\overline{\gamma}(1)) = \pi(\exp(Y))$, so there is an $h\in H$ with $g = \exp(Y)h$.  Since $H$ is connected and compact, we may write $h = \exp(X)$.  $\square$

Comment: By the way, if you want it in the other order (meaning $g = \exp(X)\exp(Y)$ with   $X\in \mathfrak{h}$ and $Y\in\mathfrak{p}$), then you can either use left coset spaces, or use my answer to write $g^{-1}$ in the "original" order, $g^{-1} = \exp(Y)\exp(X)$, and then take the inverse of both sides.